# Auto refresh hive clone table

Tags: hive, analytics, hiveql

I am working with the hive, I have created a table by using fields from a master tables.

**Sample code**

> create table final_table select feild1.feild2 from mater_table;

I need to auto update my table when master table is updated.
any suggestions pelase, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get any solution for this. Anyway, i implemented same with the help of view.

```
create view final_view select feild1.feild2 from mater_table;
```

Its ok for my requirement.